# Different binning in matplotlib hist2d?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Is it possible to have certain region in a 2D-histogram with different binning?

For example, I want to visualize data like:

```
ABCDE
FGHIJ
KLMNO
PQRST
```

where certain adjacent 2x2 bins

```
HI
MN
```

meant to be replaced with 3x3 bins:

```
a1 a2 a3
a4 a5 a6
a7 a8 a9
```

Of course I have all necessary data for it. The problem is in the visualization.

Comment: In `pyplot.hist2d` you can give the specific bin limits that you want. So you can create a 2D array with the exact positions you want for the bins: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html

Comment: Thanks Francisca, if I understand correctly bins positions in hist2d have its limitations. I tried to use such arrays for bin edges but I see the error "Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float".

Comment: As a workaround I create new arrays which bins have the least common multiple of arrays I used. I started from the Kronecker product of two arrays https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html Unfortunately it is limited by same-shape arrays. So finally I used Numpy tensordot which can be applied for any arrays: `x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) 
y = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], dtype=np.int32)`

`np.tensordot(x, y, axes=0).swapaxes(2, 1).reshape(x.shape[0] * y.shape[0],-1)`